# spring boot 2 migration problems with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started to migrate my project to spring boot 2 and while doing it I found some problems with a few configuration classes.

Most of my the dependencies of my apps are in-house spring projects so while doing the migration a lot of configuration classes started to fail due to incompatible changes. At first, I started migrating every one of the dependencies, but then I realized that I would need to migrate everything again when a new version is released. So I wanted to ask if this is the correct way to design spring apps or perhaps I should take another approach.

Comment: May I ask what's the reason for this migration? Is there a feature that available on the new version that you need to use? or is this a major release of your app(v1.x.x to v2.x.x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have spotted one of the reasons so many devs endeavor to isolate the business code from any framework. What you are encountering is also a well known issue called the ripple effect: you start to make a change in one section of the code and you find yourself propagating this change everywhere, due to software design.

I encourage you to read [this article](https://codurance.com/2015/08/17/increasing-complexity-one-entity-at-a-time/) (actually this whole blog is a gold mine for software design).

My advice at this point would be: do not engage yourrself in a straight forward migration that may crush your software down, unless you absolutely have to!

Try the following strategy instead:

1. Start reworking your components one at the time and try to isolate the business code from the spring framework.
2. Next, try to isolate the various modules of your project by creating custom interface between them. This way you will be in full control of the communication between your components.
3. Once this is achieved you shall then be able to migrate your components one at the time. Start with the least critical and work your way up to the most critical.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to follow your advice. As an example there is a filter which is packaged in a separate jar and shared between a few spring applications. Within the jar there is a configuration class:


`@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    prefix = "prefix.loggingFilter",
    name = {"filter"},
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = true
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoggingSettings.class})
`
and of course it fails as in spring 2 kebab notation for properties is required. But i think in this case it is correct to have this problem as it's a spring specific obj.